# Access the database engine could not lock table - Make Table script for fields held on the form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm having a bit of trouble with some vba script i'm attempting to run from a button on a form.

Via a linked MDB file, I've written a string of Make Table queries that help certain other queries work. Rather than have the user re-run each individual Make Table query one-by-one, I've put the queries in a VBA script (using **DoCmd.RunSQL**) and then assigned that script to a button on a form.

The data source i'm using also has a File Info table that contains the File Name and the File Date of the data.

When the user clicks the button, I'd like them to know what data source was used when the string of Make Tables queries was run; that way they know what data the script was run on.

My approach to this was to create a final Make Table query using the File Info table to put the File Name and File Date in it's own table.

I would then add these fields to the form and add the **DoCmd.RunSQL** for this final Make Table query in to the bottom of the VBA script for the button; once all the Make Tables had run, the File Info and File Date fields would then be displayed/updated on the form telling the user what data file had been used the last time the script was run.

Here's the code for this (for brevity I've summarised all the Make Table scripts that run prior to the FileInfo as some bogus "AllOtherMakeTables" string)

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_Command0_Click

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim AllOtherMakeTables As String
Dim FileInfoStamp As String

AllOtherMakeTables = " SELECT SomeField INTO AnotherTable" _
& " FROM SomeTable" _

FileInfoStamp = " SELECT FileInfo.FileName, FileInfo.FileDate INTO FileInfoStamp" _
& " FROM FileInfo;" _

DoCmd.RunSQL AllOtherMakeTables
DoCmd.RunSQL FileInfoStamp

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Exit_Command0_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_Command0_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command0_Click

End Sub
```

Clicking the button using the script above yields the following error message:

> The database engine could not lock table 'FileInfoStamp' because it is
>   already in use by another person or process

I think what is happening is the fields I added to the form (FileName and FileDate) are locking the FileInfoStamp table when the form is open, so when the script tries to recreate the FileInfoStamp it is unable to do this as the table is locked.

I thought this might be fixed simply by adding a **DoCmd.Close** at the start of the above script and then adding a **DoCmd.OpenForm** at the end of the script (essentially closing the form whilst the Make Table commands are run and then re-opening the form at the end).

All this does though is close the form and bring up the same error message. So I guess even though the form is "closed" the connections with the fields on the form still remain active in some way(...?)

Any assistance on how I might get around this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not recreate `FileInfoStamp` each time.  Use these two steps instead:

1. discard existing rows
2. append the new data

```vb
Dim db As DAO.database
Dim FileInfoStamp As String

FileInfoStamp = "INSERT INTO FileInfoStamp(FileName, FileDate)" & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT fi.FileName, fi.FileDate FROM FileInfo AS fi;"
Debug.Print FileInfoStamp

Set db = CurrentDb
' empty out FileInfoStamp
db.Execute "DELETE FROM FileInfoStamp;", dbFailOnError
' add new data to FileInfoStamp
db.Execute FileInfoStamp, dbFailOnError
Set db = Nothing
```

Add an error handler to deal with any problems turned up from `dbFailOnError`.

Instead of `DoCmd.RunSQL`, use the DAO database `.Execute` method for your other queries.  With that approach, you will not have any motivation to use `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`.  Turning `SetWarnings` off is unwise because it suppresses information you need to diagnose problems.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm somewhat new to the VBA side of access so appreciate the method and new code to look up and learn how the method works. The above method you've supplied seems to require the form to be refreshed before the new data is displayed in the fields on the form. Is there a more elegant command to refresh than the ones I currently know (`DoCmd.Close` and `DoCmd.OpenForm`)?

Comment: Yes, with VBA in the form's code module, you can say `Me.Requery`.  There is also actually a `.Refresh` method, too, but that one will only show you updates to the current rows ... not any new rows.  `Requery` gets everything.